# Supersearch not showing all results

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I have a site which is a directory of images, grouped by brand. Supersearch is hardcoded in to show a list of results on each page, depending on the brand page that you are on (using it a little like channel:entries).

The site appears to be working perfectly and displaying everything as required but I spoke to the client today who informed me that some images were not showing up in the main listings. Each image is it's own entry and has tags applied etc. and then assigned to a brand. He recreated one of the entries that wasn't showing up in the supersearch results using exactly the same image, information & tags and this time it appeared in the list.

Has anyone experienced Supersearch not showing all results, even though everything appears to be in order?

If it's any help, here is the line of code that calls the search.

{exp:super_search:results parse="inward" redirect_post="yes" search="keywords={exp:parameters:post name='keywords'}&channel=images&image_brand-exact={exp:stash:get name='brand_clean_title'}&orderby=entry_date+desc"}

Comment: How are your image entries grouped by brand? Through categories? When the client is claiming that images are not showing up, is it only the image in {my_image_field} not parsing or is there nothing inside {exp:super_search:results} displaying? Also, what are your Super Search and EE versions?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on **Template Debugging** to see if your `{exp:parameters:post}` and `{exp:stash:get}` tags are parsed correctly and before {exp:super_search:results}. If they aren't, then this might be why you're getting odd results.

Also test using hard-coded values in `{exp:super_search:results}`.

Other things you might want to check:

- Your entries have a status of "open"
- Your search keyword is found in your field within the entry, and that this field is set as **searchable**
- Try removing the `-exact` part of your search query, to open up the search to possibly more results. You can then compare data with the previous results.
- For images, and this is more general in EE, make sure the file was uploaded, the URL for your image field is correct, and the uploaded file can be accessed directly from a URL.

Answer (score 1):

This was all down to EE limiting my results to 99 even though I was trying to pull in a variable to set a higher limit. I hard-coded the limit in and it worked fine.

Supersearch is in the clear here.